# List total memusage by 32bit programs and 64bit programs

Tags: windows, batch-file, 64-bit, 32-bit

How to get the total amount of memory used by 32bit applications and 64bit applications from the command line in Windows.

I tried using `tasklist /FI "MODULES eq wow64.dll" /FO CSV` and then parsing the output and summing. But `tasklist` just freezes with any command that has something to do with modules (`tasklist /m` and `tasklist /fi "modules eq wow64.dll"` freeze).

Are there any alternatives? Or some idea why `tasklist` freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what version of windows.  Are you using a 64bit capable version of Tasklist?

Also, your title asks for a program's memory use, but your example asks for a module use - Which is more important to you?

Other tools that will give info on modules:

Listdlls.exe from Sysinternals:
Listdlls.exe -d wow64.dll
You can obtain module totals in much the same manner as your Tasklist.exe example.

Native tool:
Tlist.exe  
Less like the tasklist example because you can only get one pid at a time.  Pipe pids into a loop and use find.exe for the DLL of your choice.

Pslist.exe from sysinternals
pslist -m gives both working and virtual memory used.  Nothing about DLL's though.

Arg.  I just noticed this was posted a year ago - Hope you found an answer....

Comment: I even can't remember whether I found a solution to this. Anyway yes it was 64bit capable. `modules eq wow64.dll` is one way to get a list of 64bit programs (at least I think it is).